# Bash Script : Printing a column with having space between the string

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have run into the the wall with this problem.
When i Run ls -l command. I get this result ( I intentionally omitted the columns after 5th below for simplicity)

-rw-r--r--. 1 leslie     users   Aug 26 00:14
-rw-r--r--. 1 sherri     root    Aug 26 00:14
-rw-r--r--. 1 marie     domain users Aug 26 00:14

I want to print the Group Ownership Column. through several ways i can print 4th Column which is group ownership column . The problem is some group names have space in it .For example :- "domain users" . ls -l | awk '{print $4}' is Printing 4th column like this

users
root
domain

The output i want is

users
root
domain users

PLease help. I am stuck here from many days. 
i really need some intelligent mechanism which can detect that domain users or other groups with space name is a group name which falls under the group ownershi category. My groups are coming from Active Directory . that's why some have space in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are parsing the output of `ls`.  Don't do that.  For some of the reasons why see:  [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

As an alternative, try GNU `find`.  This will print group names:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%g\n'
```

If you want the file name displayed before the group name:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%-20f %g\n'
```

#### Finding the unique group names

The output of the above can be sent to `sort -u` to select only the unique names:

```
find / -path /proc -prune -o -printf '%g\n' | sort -u
```

Comment: Nice, but you think stat is simpler?

Comment: @sjsam `stat` is nice but not portable.   Look, for example, at the [BSD stat man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stat&sektion=1) and compare the options there with the GNU's `stat`.  There are [other unices](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175326/53604) that lack `stat` entirely.

Comment: Hmm Good note. Thankyou :)

Comment: @John1024 Awesome. Thank You so much. It worked. But is there a way to not repeat the group names.   i am trying this command                                           find / -path /proc -prune -o -printf '%g\n' | uniq  > gorupfile

Comment: @John1024 Thanks Alot man. You are a life save. I added the sort in the above command and it worked. You are a hero .

Comment: @Rick Yes, there is a trick to that: `uniq` does not work like that unless the input is sorted.  `sort` can be used to sort the input:  `find / -path /proc -prune -o -printf '%g\n' | sort | uniq`.  Many `sort` commands offer a `-u` option that eliminates the need for `uniq`.

Comment: @sjsam: I, personally, recommend familiarizing yourself with `find` on general principles. It's one of those swiss army knife utilities that can cover such a wide range of applications that *not* knowing its various features can be a real detriment if you intend to spend time on the shell. It may not be the simplest tool for any given problem, but it can be the one tool to solve *many* problems.

Comment: `-printf` is specific to GNU `find`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `stat` instead of `ls`. On Linux:

```
stat -c %G *        # Shorter,
stat --format=%G *  # Longer.
```

On BSD:

```
stat -f%Sg *
```

Comment: May be set `globstar` to do recursive listing, though not mentioned.

Comment: @choroba Thanks alot. i appreciate your answer. It is working

Comment: `stat -f%Sg` for BSD `stat`.